# Which data structure is best for this problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

There are n activities and m students. Each student can do as many activities as possible. I want to figure out the shortest path is between two students. I need to focus on inserting time of the activities: students and the time to find the shortest path between two students.
Example:
Activity1: Bob,Carl, Anthony, Suzy, David
Activity2: Bob, Manny, carl Bethany brad
Activity3: Carl, Craig, Candy

Given this if I wanted to find shortest path between
Anthony to craig
would be Anthony-> Activity1-> Bob -> Activity2-> Carl-> Activity3-> Craig
What would be the best data-structure to first insert this and then do the queries for shortest path? I believe its a graph but what type and how would I format it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph

Answer (score 0):

Bipartite graph is your solution.
one part goes for students and one part for tasks.
insertion of task is O(1) as long as you don't need any index , just contiune increasing index of task part. and insertion of student-task relation also O(1).
finding the min path is applicable with [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [dijikstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)